# Using Microsoft.Sdc.Tasks.ServiceProcess.ControlService how do I check if a service exists on a remote machine?

Tags: .net, msbuild

I'm trying to check if a service exists on a remote machine using the `Microsoft.Sdc.Tasks.ServiceProcess.ControlService` task.

```
<ControlService  MachineName="$(TargetMachineName)" Action="Exists" ServiceName="w3svc">
    <Output PropertyName="W3ServiceExists" TaskParameter="ServiceExists" />
</ControlService>
```

When I use the above task declaration I get this output from MSBUILD.

> `(42,54): error MSB4065: The "ServiceExists" parameter is not marked for output by the "ControlService" task.`

Is there a way to use the ControlService class to get whether or not a service exists on a remote machine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer was to pull the code and recompile with the `ServiceExists` property properly marked with the `[Output]` attribute.

Would recommend anyone that finds this answer look at the [MS Build Extension Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/MSBuildExtensionPack) instead as this problem doesn't exist in that set of MS Build tasks and it is more actively developed.